# Presenting UIAlertController when UISearchController is Active

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a UITableView that has a UISearchController in the navigation bar. The table view contents update as the user types in the search bar. When a row is selected another table view controller is pushed to the navigation stack. On that new table view controller, there is bar button item that presents an action sheet. The problem is that when I select a row after using the search controller and then try to open the action sheet on the new table view controller, I get

```
Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x103971800>  on <KYFB_Black_Book.MembersTableViewController: 0x103854c00> which is already presenting (null)
```

If I select a row from the first controller without searching and then open the action sheet on the second controller, everything works fine.

In viewDidLoad() of first controller:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        let searchField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        searchField?.textColor = .white

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        } else {
            searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.0, height: 44.0)
            searchField?.textColor = .black
            searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .black
            navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        }
```

Updating results based on search text:

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filteredCountyNames.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (countyNames as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
        filteredCountyNames = array as! [String]
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

In second controller, presenting the alert controller:

```
@objc func actionTapped() {
        let emailAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Contact All Committee Members", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) in
            print("Cancel")
            })
        let emailAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Email", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            self.emailAll()
            })
        let messageAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Text Message", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            self.textAll()
            })

        emailAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 28.0 / 255.0, green: 75.0 / 255.0, blue: 136.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1)
        emailAlert.addAction(emailAction)
        emailAlert.addAction(messageAction)
        emailAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(emailAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I think that issue is related to `definesPresentationContext` property

Comment: @ReinierMelian I tried setting it to true but get the same result.

Comment: @raginggoat Seems like MembersTableViewController presented something before presenting the action sheet. Are you sure you don't have anything presented?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you try this to see if it works? Just replace the last line of your code where you present the action sheet.

```
if let presentedVC = presentedViewController {
    presentedVC.present(emailAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    present(emailAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, when using a UISearchController and try to present a UIAlertController. Try this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        // To avoid the problem
        search.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to dismiss searchBar before opening UIAlearView, just show it even if searchBar is visible!